# Unable to merge dex error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

This is my app build.gradle file
[image]

It shows error in the appcompat dependecy file. I tried clean project and build project and so many ways but still the error shows. This is my error when i run project.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex**

Comment: Please enable :  multiDexEnabled true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your app.gradle file

```
 android {
          defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            }
       }
```

add the dependency also

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

it will solve your problem

Comment: i tried this but still it shows the error

Comment: try adding dex file dependency also in your dependencies section it will handle

Answer (score 1):

Do this-:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

This in your build.gradle-:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

under default config